# Primefaces p:dataTable sem a mensagem "No records found."?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

E tenho uma p:dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable var="ind" value="#{logIndPersistBean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        id="table"  rowStyleClass="odd-row, even-row">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Lista de Log
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Name" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Date" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.date}" />
                        </p:column>

                        </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

Quando eu executo uma nova pesquisa, se não retornar nenhum registro, a dataTable exibe a mensagem  "No records found.", tem alguma forma de que eu não tenha que exibir essa mensagem, apenas a lista vazia ?

Eu estou usando primefaces 4.0.

[image]

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essa mensagem é controlada pelo [atributo](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.2/core/primefaces-p/dataTable.html) `emptyMessage` da `dataTable`. Por *default* o valor do atributo é "No Records Found", mas nada te impede de mudar essa mensagem:

```
<p:dataTable var="ind" value="#{logIndPersistBean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"
             id="table" rowStyleClass="odd-row, even-row" emptyMessage="">
```

Comment: Obrigado, pensei que teria que alterar algum css !